# In Foundry, how do I iterate on a python library using a transform in another repository?

Tags: palantir-foundry

I have a python library in Foundry. I want to make changes on it, and test it against a transform in another code repository.

Foundry seems to require creating a major/minor/patch version tag on the library, which will trigger a package to be created.
Then you can load the library by tag from the transform repository.

It looks like packages can't be deleted, so iteration is not really intended.

Ideally I'd reference a development branch on the python library from my transform, and whatever packaging is required behind the scenes happens transparently, without creating permanent tagged packages.

Comment: You hit the nail on the head. We gave this feedback years ago...